# Chaining in JQuery. How it is really works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a doubt and searching  for best answer. Hope any one among us can answer.

You all might know jQuery chaining.  We can add multiple event to a HTML element in a single statement.

Like:

```
$('#emp-name').html('john').css('bgcolor', 'red').show();
```

Generally we can call one member through an object at a time.
What is specialty in jQuery by which we can call multiple members(events) same time by one object.

Thanks.

Comment: It's because each function returns the same thing - a jQuery object.

Comment: each function call on $('#emp-name') object returns $('#emp-name') object thats why you can call function one after another.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585528/i-am-not-able-to-understand-how-jquery-chaining-works

Answer (score 3):

Actually it will use only one object for `$(“#emp-name”)`.It will follow the process of chaining like

```
$(“#emp-name”).html(‘john’)
```

First it will `html` the `join` into `#emp-name` and assumes the object `$(“#emp-name”)` with `html` as single object then it will go for `css` event

```
$(“#emp-name”).html(‘john’).css(“background-color”,”red”)
```

Here it will change the bg color of the `html` in `#emp-name` and assumes the object `$(“#emp-name”).html('john')` with `css` as single object then finally goes for the `show` event

```
$(“#emp-name”).html(‘john’).css(“background-color”,”red”).show();
```

Shows the `html` with the `background-color` `red` with the `html` as `john`.
In jQuery chaining it will not create a new object for each event, but it modifies the object from `left to right` based on the events that are given in the same manner.

Comment: @ALex Char. Thats true.

Answer (score 1):

**$(selector)** = jquery object wrapped up for the given selector, on which, you can call up any of the available function of jquery.

like,

```
$(selector).show();
$(selector).css("color", "green");
```

Now, beauty of a jquery function is (show, css...), it returns the modified jquery object for the original selector.

i.e.,

```
$("#emp-name").css("color", "green")
```

will do two things,

> 1. modify the color of #emp-name to green,
> 2. return the modified $("#emp-name") object.

And, the returned object can "again" be used to call another jquery function on it.

To break below:

```
$("#emp-name").html("John").css("bgcolor","red").show();
```

will work from left-to-right,

1. $(#emp-name").html("John") == jquery object on #emp-name with html
   set to "John" => $(#emp-name")
2. $("#emp-name).css("bgcolor","red") == jquery object on #emp-name
   with bgcolor set to "red" => $("#emp-name")
3. $("#emp-name).show() == jquery object on #emp-name
   with visibility set to "show" => $("#emp-name")

Hope the mystery is now solved!! :)

Comment: Good to know that it solved your purpose. You can mark it as solution to your question. :)